# Why not show scroll bar in in my web site?

Tags: html

Why does the scroll bar not show in in my web site?

Link http://vistacars.in/sell-car-free.html

Here is another link
http://vistacars.in/contact.php

Comment: Note that questions of the form "please see my website here" are not suitable for Stack Overflow. This is because after the problem is fixed, the question will no longer make any sense for future readers, and will thus need to be deleted. In future, please put everything required to understand the problem _in the question itself_. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because your website's body has css styling that tells the overflow to be hidden. You should remove this, and the scrollbars will be back.

```
.body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; <------- Remove that!
}
```